# Having troubles installing Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, failed-installation

I'm having problems installing VS Community 2015.
The installation gets stuck at `Applying LocalESPCui for en-us Dev12`.
I've read a few topics about this but still cannot figure out a solution.

Does anyone know where Visual Studio installer download the installation files?
And if possible, is there a way to resolve this problem?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You might try running the install "as administrator"

Comment: I already did when the problem occurred. Looks like some batch files are missing but I have no idea how to restore them.
I'm trying to download the iso instead of using the auto installer, I read that it solved the problem for some people, but I'm not sure. Hopefully I'm not wasting time on it.

Comment: I added 2015 in title Angelo this problem is only with visual studio 2015

Comment: Yes I noticed that. It's true however, I can confirm that based on the results on my research, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following topic will probably help you out with your problem:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98e02d60-21a8-401d-8453-c9b5ade56730/stuck-installing-localespcui-for-enus-dev12?forum=vssetup

Just make sure that the espC path exists before and during the installation. Check the logs when the you reach the point where it's stuck and verify the path.

good luck

Comment: Hello Andres,
I actually was checking that topic and after several hours I finally managed to figure out the problem. As you said the espc path didn't exist, so what I did is manually create it and copy-paste the files from the ISO that I had downloaded to it. Thanks however!

Answer (score 11):

Hope this can help:-

1. Use Task Manager to terminate vs_xxx.exe.
2. Download the ISO from microsoft.com, and mount it (say, Drive E)
3. Copy E:\packages\EspC (directory and files) to a temp location (say D:\Temp)
4. [Step 3 is important, so don't skip it].
5. In Windows Explorer, right click on "D:\Temp\EspC\LocalESPCui for en-us Dev12-x86_en-us.msi" and select *Install*.
6. Run vs_xxx.exe again.

Answer (score 1):

Running the install as Admin from the ISO it was looking in the "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\" folder and failing to find what it needed.

The installer asked me to locate the missing file. I pointed it to "E:\packages\EspC" (where E: is my mounted ISO drive letter) and found the "LocalESPCui for en-us Dev12-x86_en-us.msi".

Now the rest of the install can proceed.

Note that if the installer doesn't stop and ask you for the file you may be able to force it by removing "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\" (temporarily).